# Get Customer Name if its logged in otherwise return message in API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, postman

**I am trying to get the customer's name by POST Method API if it's logged in but when I hit the link the postman, returns the Customer's Name even if it's not logged in. Please take a look**

**CODE:**

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Login\Model\Customer;

use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

//use Vendor\Login\Controller\Index\ApiController;

/**
 * Implementing the logic
 */
class Extra
{
    protected AuthorizationLink $ath;
    protected UserContextInterface $userContext;
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected Session $customerSession;
    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement;
    /**
     * @var Url
     */
    protected Url $customerUrl;
    protected JsonFactory $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Url $customerUrl
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     * @param UserContextInterface $userContext
     * @param AuthorizationLink $ath
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Url $customerUrl,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
        Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        UserContextInterface $userContext,
        AuthorizationLink $ath

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->userContext = $userContext;
        $this->ath = $ath;

    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @param string $password
     * @return array[]
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function login(string $email, string $password): array
    {
        $validate = array();
        $login = array();
        $result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $customerinfo = array();

        if ($email) {
            $login['username'] = $email;
        }
        if ($password) {
            $login['password'] = $password;
        }

        try {

            if (($email == null) || ($password == null)) {
                $message = __('Invalid Username');

                return array($message);
            } 

            else {


                $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($email, $password);

                $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);

                $this->customerSession->regenerateId();

                if (!$this->ath->isLoggedIn()) {
                    $customer_data = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getData();

                    $customerinfo = array(
                        "name" => $customer_data['firstname'] . $customer_data['lastname']
                    );

                    return array($customerinfo);

                }
                else {

                    $error = __('Error');
                    return array($error);
                }
            }

        } 
        catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            $new = __('You are not logged in');
            return array($new);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use it like this. This code will return customer tokens if logged in so hopefully, this will help a lot.

```
<?php

$userDataArr = ["username" => "test@gmail.com", "password" => "654321"];
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/rest/V1/integration/customer/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userDataArr));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userDataArr))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

//Get customer info
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/rest/V1/customers/me");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); // Get method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Comment: Where to put this code? with above one or replace the above code with yours one?

Comment: I just give you an example to understand the logic of this code. I do not know what you wrote inside your file because we have to put some dependencies inside the constructor etc... if you were not able to get my point then send me the file name full of code.

Comment: Can you please just tell me how to get customers logged in session in API, Any Library?

Comment: The code I wrote above that will help you to get a customer token in API if the customer is logged in. Either you can create another function and create the above API and return the customer token. But it would be better then you can share the file code, I want to see what functions and dependencies you have passed inside.

Comment: Please update your question with the full path code. Open that file press Ctrl+A and replace it with the above code.

Comment: I have updated the code, please check

Comment: The code format is weird, Is it possible to use the Wetransfer link and attach your file and give me that URL?

Comment: Here is the link https://we.tl/t-gZHaldEUmp 
It has Module

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I am working on it... please give me 1-2 hours... I just finished to installed a new Magento setup on my localhost so now I will install your module and will update you.

Comment: Okay, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a new `POST` request in `POSTMAN`

Using below url

```
http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=customer_email_id&password=customer_password
```

Change `customer_email_id` in url with the customer's email you want to get the name

And Change `customer_password` in url with the customer's password and also change `http://localhost/magento2` with your project url

It will return a token, you need to copy that token

**NEXT STEP**

Now open your custom request where you are getting customer name

Go to Authorization Tab and choose **`Bearer Token`**

Now copy the token generated in previous request and page in **`Bearer Token`** in your request

It will verify the customer token and print your output

Hope it will work for you!

Please let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: I followed your steps but it returned the customer name I checked Magento frontend and the customer is not logged in. Same Issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: So first I got the token and then added the auth bearer token in my custom request, it returned the customer name in output but the customer was not logged in Magento 2. I want to get the customer's name when I logged in. That's it

Comment: In your webapi.xml file update <resource ref="anonymous"/> from anonymous to self. <resource ref="self"/> Then follow the above step

Comment: I followed the same steps after replacing "anonymous" with "self", But still the same issue. it returned the customer name but customer is logged out

Comment: Still not working? I think there is any issue with your code

Comment: I have uploaded my module in this link https://we.tl/t-gZHaldEUmp , Please take a look

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/adcqvr try updated module

Comment: Same Issue, Returned the Customer Name Even customer is logged out

Comment: How you are validating for logged out user? –

Comment: By using Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session.